# XPath 1.0: moving first item in a nodeset to last position

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

Given an XML document

```
<items>
 <item><key></key><value>empty</value></item>
 <item><key>A</key><value>foo</value></item>
 <item><key>C</key><value>data</value></item>
 <item><key>B</key><value>bar</value></item>
</items>
```

Given the /items/item nodeset, I wish to move the first item to the last position while keeping all other items at the same position.

Unusable approaches:

- | union operator keeps document order.
- `<xsl:sort>` I only want to move an item, not sort entire list of items.

Expected result:

```
<items>
 <item><key>A</key><value>foo</value></item>
 <item><key>C</key><value>data</value></item>
 <item><key>B</key><value>bar</value></item>
 <item><key></key><value>empty</value></item>
</items>
```

Note: the item to move can be identified by first position or empty key (if that's helpful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you.

```
<!--  Identity template  -->  
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- Output attributes, if any. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <!-- Out item(s) that are not first. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() != 1]"/>
    <!-- Output the first item. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() = 1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I took since it is idempotent as well.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is using the following template in combination with the *identity template*:

```
<xsl:template match="item[1]">                     <!-- matches the first item element -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*"/>   <!-- copies all but the first element -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>                      <!-- copies the current/first element -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<item>
    <key>A</key>
    <value>foo</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key>C</key>
    <value>data</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key>B</key>
    <value>bar</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key/>
    <value>empty</value>
</item>
```

Adding the *identity template* surrounds that with the `items` element to give the complete, desired output.

Comment: Thanks, this is strictly speaking an answer to the question, but is not idempotent (cannot be run repeatedly with the same output).